# How to end to end test a web application?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, end-to-end

As far as I know, end to end tests are black box tests, so I should not know anything about the application, just use its interface and check the result... But how should I check a read-only api, if I cannot touch the database to set the data I intend to read with it?

Is it really crucial to write the fixtures with an e2e approach? In my current case, I have a www and a members subdomain. The content of the www subdomain is managed from the member's subdomain with proper authorization. I want to develop with tdd beginning with the e2e tests ending with the unit tests... If I want to develop the www subdomain first, I cannot make an e2e fixture, because the data writing is not implemented yet. Should I first implement the member's subdomain if I want to develop this way? I intend to use event sourcing, so it would be very easy to make a DB fixture, just inserting some domain events, that would be all...

I don't understand the logic of this kind of testing, if I cannot insert anything to the database, it will be empty at the beginning. But then I won't have a user with proper authorization, so I cannot write into the database, and so I cannot test anything. So this is a catch-22... At least I have to have a test user with the proper authorization, but making a test user requires writing to the database... I think my brain burned out :D

Comment: If it's a read-only API, then you shouldn't be setting anything, which is the point. You'll need to find another route to add the data you need to help you test your situation if you can't touch the database.

Comment: Ofc. it's not ready only, but it requires authorization to write the data from a different sub-domain. The actual domain has only read capabilities and I want to develop it with tdd. I intend to write first e2e tests, next integration test, and at the end the unit tests...
Is there a recommended way to create fixtures for end to end tests, or how should I write them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tests need data to test against, even black box testing. Typically you will have a setup function that populates your database with data before the test runs. You will likely have a teardown step as well, which might restore the database to a pre-test state. This in no way violates any rules of testing.